# Kendo UI TreeList - Child Aggregate Hide

Tags: aggregate, kendo-treelist

In my application, need to show level based records in report. i am using Kendo UI Treelist with aggregate. Data's are showing well and grand total are showing in all level rows. But i need to show grand total in parent (Top) level node only.
It's possible to show aggregate in parent(Top) node only. Any Property available? or any alter native?

Sample URL :
https://dojo.telerik.com/AVeNuluP

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in Kendo Angular Tree list,
This feature is not available. Please refer below link, it is created by telerik team to develop this feature depends on business vote,

https://feedback.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/1511260-footer-template-only-for-some-nodes

In JQuery Kendo Tree list,
We achieved this by below code in **databound** event.

```js
$('#grid3 .k-grid-content tbody tr.divfooterrow').remove();
$('#grid3 .k-grid-content tbody').append('<tr class="divfooterrow" data-parentid="null" style="display: table-row;"><td role="gridcell" class="locationName divselected"><span class="k-icon k-i-none"></span></td><td role="gridcell" class="txtalgrit toBeActionedCount">' + qrVMSummary.totalToBeActionedCount.toLocaleString() + '</td><td role="gridcell" class="txtalgrit">' + qrVMSummary.totalToBeActionedPayout.toLocaleString() + '</td><td role="gridcell" class="txtalgrit"> ' + qrVMSummary.totalActionedCount.toLocaleString() + '</td><td role="gridcell" class="txtalgrit">' + qrVMSummary.totalActionedPayout.toLocaleString() + '</td><td role="gridcell" class="colId" style="display: none;"></td><td role="gridcell" class="colParentId" style="display: none;"></td><td role="gridcell" class="colLocationCode" style="display: none;"></td></tr>');
```